# Dfs and Mapreduce in hadoop 2.4.1

Tags: java, xml, hadoop, mapreduce, port

Am using hadoop 2.4.1, When I try to use dfs in hadoop 2.4.1, Everything is working fine. I always use start-dfs.sh script to start so the following services will be up and running in the system
     datanode, namenode and secondary namenode - which is exactly fine

Yesterday, I try to configure the mapred.xml in etc/hadoop/mapred.xml as following

```
**conf/mapred-site.xml:**

<configuration>
 <property>
     <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
     <value>localhost:9001</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

and I did the following
     1.Formatted the namenode
     2. I started start-all.sh

When I look into the logs, only following logs are available,

```
1. hadoop-datanode.log + out
2. hadoop-namenode.log + out
3. hadoop-secondarynamenode.log + out
4. yarn-nodemanager.log + out
5. yarn-resourcemanager.log + out
```

When I gave jps, only following services were running,

```
1. secondarynamenode
2. namenode
3. datanode
4. nodemanager
5. resourcemanager
```

**I dont find the job tracker there, moreover mapreduce logs are also not available, Is that we need to specify something for mapreduce in haddop 2.4.1**

Additional info, I checked with web console port of 50030 - job tracker, which is not available,

I grepped with the port check of 9001 nothing is running

Anyhelp is accepted pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Hadoop 2.0 onwards mapreduce default processing framework has been changed from classic mapreduce to YARN. When you use `start-all.sh` for starting hadoop, it internally invokes `start-yarn.sh` and `start-dfs.sh`.

If you wanted to use mapreduce instead of yarn, use should start dfs and mapreduce service separately using start-dfs.sh and start-mapred.sh( mapreduce1 binaries are located inside the directory `${HADOOP_HOME}/bin-mapreduce1` and all configuration files are under the directory `${HADOOP_HOME}/etc/hadoop-mapreduce1`).

All YARN and HDFS start up scrips are located in the sbin directory in your hadoop home, where you cannot find start-mapred.sh script. start-mapred.sh script is in the directory bin-mapreduce1.

Comment: Excellent, Could u pls tell me the complete process to start the mapreduce ! ${HADOOP_HOME}/bin-mapreduce1 -> I dont understand this context... Pls explain me the steps...

Comment: h4ck3r, pls get back to here

Comment: Are you using tarball installation ?. If yes, what is the value for the environment variable HADOOP_HDFS_HOME  ?

Comment: Its file path is like this hadoop-2.4.1/etc/hadoop, Inside this path hdfs-site.xml, mapred-site.xml and other xmls are available then

Comment: Agree, that's the location of your configuration directory. path of start-mapred.sh is hadoop-2.4.1/bin-mapreduce1/start-mapred.sh

Comment: hadoop-2.4.1/bin-mapreduce1/start-mapred.sh is not there, only these files are available there hadoop - which we use for formatting and command execution, hdfs, mapred, rcc, yarn thats it

Comment: If possible tell me the site where you find the perfect 2.4.1 hadoop version

Comment: If you are interested in using apache hadoop, it is available in the  link http://mirror.sdunix.com/apache/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.4.1/hadoop-2.4.1.tar.gz

Comment: I got it! Could u pls tell me the list of client map reduce jars we need to add for 2.4.1